# What does the rebus say?

Tags: rebus

Here is a rebus. Can you find out what does it say?
[image]

Comment: Welome to Puzzling SE! Please feel free to take the tour (you'll get a badge for it too ;)

Comment: It's a person doing a push-up... Voting to close as too broad since you could make anything of that imho.

Comment: Was any answer correct?

Answer (score 2):

I think it says

> Push up and push down

Answer (score 2):

Is it:

> Down the pike

I think this because:

> This is a phrase and the man is going down from a piked position.

Or, it could be a trick question and simply be:

> A push up.

Answer (score 0):

I think it says

> Get farther get closer

Answer (score 0):

I may be reading too far into it, but I think it says

> Line up straight.

Why?

> In the first picture, his body is at about 45 degrees with a line on his shorts, both angled up.  In the second picture, his body is at a straight line parallel to the floor as well as the line on his shorts.  Overall we have both the body and the line angled up in a push-up position, then they become straight.